# How can I adjust my code to allow it to loop back with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, if-statement, conditional-statements

I've looked over tutorials but don't particularly understand the concept.

I'm trying to get my while loop work with multiple conditions/if statements:

```
while True:
    user_input = raw_input('\n: ').upper()
    if user_input == 'NORMAL':
        user_input = 'Normal'
    if re.match('(ABC|Normal|XY)', user_input):
        check_input = cleaned_dict.get(user_input)
    if not check_input:
        print 'Nope'
    if check_input:
        print 'Yep...'
        etc...
        break
```

However, I receive an error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'check_input' referenced before assignment
```

...Due to it not looping when the regex pattern does not match.

With only 1 condition it works perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options, but the issue is that `check_input` is not assigned unless there is a regex match. You can either initialize `check_input` to `False` outside the loop or add an `else` clause. I'll show the latter

```
while True:
    user_input = raw_input('\n: ').upper()
    if user_input == 'NORMAL':
        user_input = 'Normal'
    if re.match('(ABC|Normal|XY)', user_input):
        check_input = cleaned_dict.get(user_input)
    else:
        check_input = False
    if not check_input:
        print 'Nope'
    if check_input:
        print 'Yep...'
    etc...
    break
```